# What would differ between these simple codes?

Tags: python, class, object

So I've been kinda new to some concepts, can someone please briefly explain what is the difference between these two codes?

```
regressor=LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(train_X,train_Y)
```

.

```
LinearRegression().fit(train_X,train_Y)
```

Comment: What concepts are you new to? What do you believe is the difference between these two and why are you curious?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your comments. I am fairly new to structures of classes and the hierarchy while accessing something in outer libraries. As I can see, the difference is that first two lines of code creates an object using the LinearRegressin() class while the bottom code does not (?) create one. What I couldn't understand is why we do or do not create an object if we can directly access the library/class. My curiosity is because I want to understand these basics fundementally.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between the two is that the first creates a variable called `regressor` which you can later access.  The second doesn't do this.

Otherwise the two are doing exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of fitting (training) the regressor is to use *it* in the future for prediction. In you r second example (`LinearRegression().fit(train_X,train_Y)`) you create an anonymous regressor, train it, and then immediately discard. You cannot use it anymore as it does not have any references.

In the first example, you first create a regressor and assign it to a variable, then train the regressor that was previously created. You can later use it for prediction or any other purpose.

Comment: This might only be useful in cases of benchmarking or to check that this does not raise any exceptions.